# boost_python3 missing from ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, git, ubuntu, numpy, boost

I am trying to install boost.numpy in y Ubuntu 16.04. I tried these commnads to install boost.numpy

```
**git clone https://github.com/ndarray/Boost.NumPy.git
 cd Boost.NumPy && mkdir build && cd build
 cmake -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=$HOME/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.5m.so ../**
```

After doing cmake i am facing this error:

Detected architecture 'x86_64'

```
-- Using Python3

    CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1677 (message):
      Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.59.0
  Boost include path: /home/sumit/Documents/Software/boost_1_59_0
  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_python3

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:48 (find_package)


 Boost Paths:
Include  : /home/sumit/Documents/Software/boost_1_59_0
 **Libraries**: /home/sumit/Documents/Software/boost_1_59_0/libs
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

See also "/home/sumit/Documents/Software/Boost.NumPy/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Previously it was not able to find the boost libraries sp i manualy changed the CmakeList.txt library path with the path of boost_1_59_0 lib path. This path comes up in library option when i do cmake. But still boost_python3 is missing. I am new into this what i tried is just the result of google.
Please help.

Comment: Are you trying to use development versions or official released versions?

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu the library names for boost are:
`libboost_python`, `libboost_python-py35`, or `libboost_python-py27`

This means that in `cmake` you'll need to refer to them as `python-py35` instead of `python3`. Alternatively, if you don't control the `CMakeLists.txt` you can create a symlink:
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py35.so` -> `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python3.so`

In my `CMakeLists.txt` file I have the following:

```
if(UNIX)
    set( BOOST_PYTHONLIB python-py35)
else()
    set( BOOST_PYTHONLIB python3)
endif()

find_package (Boost 1.58 REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    coroutine
    context
    filesystem
    program_options
    system
    thread
    ${BOOST_PYTHONLIB}
    chrono
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer for this is that wherever *boost_python3* is specified, 
you replace it with *boost_python-py35*.

I tried this when I was setting up caffe for python 3.5 . In the *Makefile.config* file, I only made the above changes and it worked fine for me.